# How can I get the source of chat without using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests

So my issue is that, I want to get user's **id** info from the chat.

The chat area what I'm looking for, looks like this...

```
<div id="chat_area" class="chat_area" style="will-change: scroll-position;">
<dl class="" user_id="asdf1234"><dt class="user_m"><em class="pc"></em> :</dt><dd id="1">blah blah</dd></dl>
<a href="javascript:;" user_id="asdf1234" user_nick="asdf1234" userflag="65536" is_mobile="false" grade="user">asdf1234</a>
...
```

What I want do is to, 
Get the part starting with `<a href='javascript:'' user_id='asdf1234' ...` 
so that I can parse this and do some other stuffs.

But this webpage is the one I'm currently using, and it can not be proxy(webdriver by selenium).

How can I extract that data from the chat?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got two separate problems here. I'd use both the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries to accomplish this.

Use your browser's developer tools, the network tab, to refresh the page and look for the request which responds with the HTML you want. Use the requests library to emulate this request exactly.

```
import requests

headers = {"name": "value"}

# Get case example.
response = requests.get("some_url", headers=headers)

# Post case example.
data = {"key": "value"}
response = requests.post("some_url", headers=headers, data=data)
```

Web-scraping is always finicky, if this doesn't work you're most likely going to need to use a requests session. Or a one-time hacky solution is just to set your cookies from the browser.

Once you have made the request you can use BeautifulSoup to scrape your user id very easily.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create BS parser.
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

# Find all elements with the attribute "user_id".
find_results = soup.findAll("a", {"user_id" : True})

# Iterate results. Could also just index if you want the single user_id.
for result in find_results:
    user_id = result["user_id"]
```

Comment: You know, I tried the network tab to get the request.url, and I get a weird thing. Since this is a chat of a live-streaming, it keeps changing. And it keeps adding. Then how can I get it?

Comment: @HyeonPhilYoun I can't really help with the details because the process is different in each case. You need to figure out how the client is receiving chat messages from the server, and re-implement this in your code.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but these chats are provided through javascript, I can't find any `user_id` or chat in response...It's not in iframe, maybe I need to dig into other ways..